# spring-boot web service with money/decimal type

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, spring-ws

I have simple spring-boot application with soap webservice:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/
In xsd I have added custom bigdecimal type (money type).

```
     <xs:complexType name="country">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="population" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="currency" type="tns:currency" />
            <xs:element name="value1" type="xs:decimal" />
            <xs:element name="value2" type="tns:money" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="money">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:fractionDigits value="2" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

CountryRepository class:

```
    Country spain = new Country();
    spain.setName("Spain");
    spain.setCapital("Madrid");
    spain.setCurrency(Currency.EUR);
    spain.setPopulation(46704314);
    spain.setValue1(new BigDecimal(1.2));
    spain.setValue2(new BigDecimal(2.1));

    countries.add(spain);
```

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gs="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <gs:getCountryRequest>
         <gs:name>Spain</gs:name>
      </gs:getCountryRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:getCountryResponse xmlns:ns2="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
         <ns2:country>
            <ns2:name>Spain</ns2:name>
            <ns2:population>46704314</ns2:population>
            <ns2:capital>Madrid</ns2:capital>
            <ns2:currency>EUR</ns2:currency>
            <ns2:value1>1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875</ns2:value1>
            <ns2:value2>2.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625</ns2:value2>
         </ns2:country>
      </ns2:getCountryResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How to fix decimal output?
I would like to have :

```
<ns2:value2>2.10</ns2:value2>
```

Comment: You need a specialized mapper to do this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html

Comment: You are losing precision by invoking the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor.  Read the JavaDocs for that constructor that clearly highlight this.  If you are only creating an example application for the time being, you could use the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor as `new BigDecimal("1.2")`.  For actual applications, it is always better to wrap a `BigDecimal` into your domain-specific class such as `Money` and apply the required formatting within the custom class.

Comment: @manish: Thanks. You are right. The problem is with double type. I have replaced it with BigDecimal fetched from oracle database and it's ok now.

Comment: @Marged: Do you have any example? Unfortunately, jaxb2-maven-plugin did not generate any adnotations on value2 (value1 and value2 are same BigDecimal type). What if I would like to control precision of bigdecimal on schema level...is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
  // step 1
  BigDecimal valueOne = new BigDecimal(2.1);
  BigDecimal valueTwo = new BigDecimal(2.1);

  // step 2
  valueOne.setScale(2);
  valueTwo.setScale(2);

  //step 3
  spain.setValue1(new BigDecimal(1.2));
  spain.setValue2(new BigDecimal(2.1));

  //console -> valueOne -> 1.2
  //console -> valueTwo -> 2.1
```